# How to avoid duplicated data FS node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to use FS to dynamically add lines on the top of my file. That part is working but how can I avoid duplications? This is my code:

```
function writeData() {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('../common.js');
    const fd = fs.openSync('../common.js', 'w+');
    const buffer = new Buffer.from(`${importString};\n`);

    fs.writeSync(fd, buffer);
    fs.writeSync(fd, data);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean make sure the `importString` isn't already written to the file? You have the current content in `data` - can't you just look inside of that and not bother writing if it's there? If you tried and it's not working, show what you tried and we can help.

Comment: Hey @AlwaysLearning yes! The problem is that the `data` comes like a Buffer, it returns like a hex number.

Comment: try doing `const text = data.toString()` then scanning the text for duplicates